# Bootstrap - How to show modal box using option from select?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I enable modal box on Bootstrap using `<option>` from `<select>` I tried the default way but it's not working.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus()
});

<select class="form-control">
    <option>select</option>
    <option data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Second Option</option>
</select>
```

See my **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/umnv2p1t/)** for a better clarification.

Comment: but it's working in fiddle

Comment: How come? When I select "Second Option" the modal box doesn't show.

Comment: then you need to refresh the fiddle, it's working, on "Second Option" modal does open

Comment: Nope, it's not working here. Can you update and paste the link here for us please?

Comment: this is your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/umnv2p1t/ it working and this one i made some changes in the code  http://jsfiddle.net/umnv2p1t/2/ both fiddles working modal does show

Comment: That's weird. My fiddle still doesn't work here. After you made your changes, it's working now. =) Thanks! You can add your changes as an answer to the question if you want.

Comment: if this is the exact solution you are looking will make it answer with explanation ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Still not sure why OP insisting fiddle in question not working where I can see it's working may be I have too much coffee today :)

Quick solution is assign id to `<select>` in HTML `<select class="form-control" id="myselect">`

```
<select class="form-control" id="myselect">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="secondoption">Second Option</option>
</select>
```

Add `value` in `select` options and taking advantage of [jQuery Change Function](https://api.jquery.com/change/) get `value` of Second Option and use [Comparison Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)
to compare value and if value `true`,  can open the modal with [Bootstrap JS Modal](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp) via JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //Make script DOM ready
    $('#myselect').change(function() { //jQuery Change Function
        var opval = $(this).val(); //Get value from select element
        if(opval=="secondoption"){ //Compare it and if true
            $('#myModal').modal("show"); //Open Modal
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umnv2p1t/2/)

Comment: Actually I didn't have enough coffee today! But thanks that's exactly what I was looking for. =)